# How to set printer permissions using PowerShell / some other script?

Tags: windows, printer, powershell, wmi

I need to update printer's permissions in a script, i.e. do the same as I would manually do this way:

1. Open *Devices and Printers* applet
2. Double-click the default printer (open its queue)
3. Go to *Printer -> Properties*
4. In the properties dialog, go to *Security* tab
5. Change permissions for *Everyone* (e.g., check *Manage documents* permissions)

How to do that? For example, in PowerShell, I can do

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_printer -filter Default=True
```

to get the default printer and there are then methods `getSecurityDescriptor()` and `setSecurityDescriptor()` but for instance this command:

```
(Get-WmiObject -class win32_printer -filter Default=True).getsecuritydescriptor().Descriptor
```

return null so I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way.

Does anyone have a working example to set printer permissions? Am I on the right path or should I use something other than WMI entirely? Thanks.

Comment: Is this in a domain or a workgroup? Also, will you set the permissions for groups, users, or both?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PowerShell, I have only done printer permissions directly using .NET and WMI, and it can get messy as the permissions are made up of the **SecurityDescriptor**, which has a **Descriptor** property, which has a **DACL** property, which contains one or more **Win32_ACE** objects, each of which contains **AccessMask, AceFlags, and Trustree** which is a **Win32_Trustee** object which contains who the permission applies to.

There maybe a PowerShell addon that simplifies setting the above, alternatively take a look at the [SetACL command line tool](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/examples/managing-printer-service-and-share-permissions-with-setacl-exe/) which you could call from PowerShell.